# Template specialization for recursive type

Tags: c++, templates

I am working on creating an instrumentation class for a large code repository, to that end i created a class like the following:

```
template <class T> class stats:public singleton<stats<T> >{...};
```

The singleton class is defined as you would expect from the above, and is not a class i have control over. Because i only want one stat instance per type i am gathering stats on it should be a singleton, and in our code base we forbid custom singleton classes (otherwise i would implement my own singleton interface and thus prevent the problem i am facing)
The problem is that i want to tool the singleton as well, so the following will occur:

```
someTooledClass();
-> stats<someTooledClass>
-> singleton<stats<someTooledClass> >
-> stats<singleton<stats<someTooledClass> > >
etc.
```

My question is can i specialize `stats<singleton<T> >`? Because T is unknown i am unsure how this would even work.
Ideally i wouldn't want `stats<singleton<stats<T> > >` to ever exist but all other `stats<singleton<T> >` i do want. 
I just have never really done anything like this before... so i'm a bit confused.

Edit:
I guess i'll put this here for visibility reasons. 
Tooling singleton is possible because i am globally overriding new and delete to my own custom ones for all classes in the build, as singleton is in the build path (indeed it must be) i can tool it in this way.
For background the task i was given is to create a memory manager so i know what i am getting into with that (i think... but that is really a separate issue anyway). but for now i am trying to gather statistics on all currently used memory allocations segregated by what type, not just by size class.

Comment: "`singleton` ... is not a class I have control over" ... "I want to tool the singleton as well".  Sounds like a conflicting requirement.

Comment: Where is it that you are adding code that allows you to "tool the singleton"?

Comment: i am global overriding new, which will create an instance of stats<T> if needed and then returns the value they asked for (after collecting the needed metrics.)

Comment: @Robopanda333: Normally `operator new` is never called for a singleton.  Furthermore, global `operator new` doesn't know what type it is allocating memory for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it?

Note that you can't make the class not exist, however you can make it not inherit from singleton, in order to break the chain.

```
template <class T>
class stats<singleton<stats<T> > > {};
```

Comment: i know that what i have breaks in a fabulous manner (i have a global redefined new, that news my class... yay!)
i didn't know that i could change the class definition for a specific specialization, but that makes sense. i'll try this and see what happens.

Comment: isn't exactly what i want, as you said. but it does solve the problem.